# export/zip eclipse project via java program for Windows and MAC

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, macos, export

I need to export a (java) eclipse project without using eclipse. I tried to copy all relevant files and pack them with a ZipOutputStream. So good so far, I can load this zip-file in Windows. But **MAC users** have the problem, that the **file structure is not automaticaly detected** and create files with names like "vorlage\src\de\tuberlin..." next to the src directory.
[(example picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1qLs.png)

Is there a way to properly export an eclipse project with a java programm?

The reason is that I created programming exercises for a lecture and marked the solutions with special comments. During copying the files these comments and the solutions are left out.

One solution would be importing the zip-file in Windos and exporting again with the help of eclipse. But this costs a lot of time doing this for each exercise.

Although I cannot see any difference between the two zip-files, there seems to be something.

Here my code to copy the files:

```
public static void copyDir(File source, File target, ArrayList<String> exclude)
throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    File[] files = source.listFiles();
    File newFile = null;
    target.mkdirs();
    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            newFile = new File(target.getAbsolutePath() + System.getProperty("file.separator") + files[i].getName());
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                copyDir(files[i], newFile, exclude);
            }
            else if ( !exclude.contains(files[i].getName()) ) {
                copyFile(files[i], newFile);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void copyFile(File file, File target) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    if (file.getName().endsWith(".java")) {
        copyJavaFile(file, target);
        return;
    }

    BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(target, true));
    int bytes = 0;
    while ((bytes = in.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(bytes);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}


private static void copyJavaFile(File file, File target) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(target);
    boolean stopped = false;
    String line = null;
    while ( (line = in.readLine() ) != null) {
        stopped |= line.contains("IF EXCLUDE");
        if (!stopped && !line.contains("ENDIF"))
            out.println(line);
        stopped &= !line.contains("ELSE");
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

I copy the following (sub-)directories/files:

- .settings
- src
- .classpath
- .project

I create the zip-file with:

```
public Zip(final File projDir, final File outFile) {
    ZipOutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new ZipOutputStream(
                    new BufferedOutputStream(
                        new FileOutputStream(outFile)));
        for (File file : projDir.listFiles()) {
            writeFiles(file, output, "");
        }
        output.finish();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println("IO Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {output.close();} catch (IOException ex) {}
    }
}

private void writeFiles(File f, ZipOutputStream output, String dir) throws IOException {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        // recursively write files in directory
        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
            writeFiles(file, output, dir + f.getName() + File.separator);
        }
    } else {
        // write this file to archive
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(dir + f.getName());
        entry.setTime(f.lastModified());
        output.putNextEntry(entry);
        copy(fis, output);
        output.closeEntry();
        fis.close();
    }
}

private void copy(InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytes;
    while ((bytes = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        os.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're example image requires a login to the forum, edit this with a version we can all access. Imgur/puush are all good for image hosting.

Comment: You might also want to edit your post to include some code of stuff that you've tried so far. Refer to the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you want to know more about what makes a question a good quesiton for SO

Comment: Probably not really helpful, but I can't resist: next time, think about using a build system like graddle upfront. What you are actually trying to do is to manually put together certain build artifacts. Instead, you should have a tool doing that for you. In the good old days, you would have used ANT; and just provided a special plugin to modify the copied Java files. I hope your students are not aware that their instructor has such problems. And seriously; instead of pulling together an errorprone manual process; I would rather spent a day to learn how to do this with ant, maven, gradle...

Comment: When you create the ZIP file you probably use the Windows path separator char "\" `backslash`. Try to use the Unix one "/" `slash` this should work in both worlds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a problem of the path separator. Using "/" instead of "File.separator" solves the problem.
In the example above the for-loop in the method writeFiles(...) must be:

```
for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
    writeFiles(file, output, dir + f.getName() + "/");
}
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549766/create-zip-file-in-windows-and-extract-zip-file-in-linux).